# Configuring Knockout validation in Durandal / SPA application

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, single-page-application, durandal, knockout-validation

I am not able to get knockout.validation up and running with durandal. knockout itself is working fine. If anyone got this straight I would be thankful for posting the configuration.

```
// main.js
require.config({
    paths: {
    "libs": "../scripts",
    "knockout": "../scripts/knockout-2.2.1",
    'knockout.validation': '../scripts/knockout.validation'
},
shim: {
    'knockout.validation': {
        deps: ["knockout"]
    }
}
});

define(function (require) {
validation = require('libs/knockout.validation')
// other dependencies are omitted
ko.validation = validation;
// ko works fine
// ko validation has been set
}

// my viewmodel
define(['services/logger',
'durandal/app',
'durandal/system',
'durandal/plugins/router',
'services/dataservice'],
function (logger, app, system, router, dataservice) {

var user_name = ko.observable().extend( {required: true } );
var user_password = ko.observable().extend( {required: true });

// Unable to get property 'extend' of undefined or null reference
// the same happens, if I define '/libs/knockout.validation locally
```

Does kockout.validation behaves different than other plugins?

Comment: You are at risk of being down-voted and closed - can you post any code of what you have tried and what is not working?  This should be fairly simple if you have used Knockout validation before.

Comment: I am trying to figure out the helping part of your comment. Are you practically working with durandal, knockout and knockout validation within a SPA application? If not, thank you for reading the question but then you are not the desired adressee. Have a great day and thanks for contributing.

Comment: Yep, sure am / do.  This question does not follow the standards here for stack overflow

Comment: Well, then thank you in advance. Have a great day, Günther

Comment: Check here https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/issues/259 - Basically Knockout validation doesn't play well with require.js, which Durandal uses during development and before you optimize your app.  Not beautiful but should answer your question

Comment: Ty PW Kad. Please provide this as an answer - I'll flag that as a solution. Well, I've read that before - the problem still persists. Anyway - it might not be the configuration itself but a combination of improper usage of this lib within my code. I'll open another question and trying to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, knockout validation doesn't play well yet with require.js at the moment.  Durandal relies on require.js during development until you optimize your app.

This link details a work around for now.

http://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/issues/259

Answer (score 4):

Here is an working example of knockout validation and durandal vm;

```
define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app', 'config'],function (router, app, config) {

    ko.validation.init({
        messagesOnModified: false
    });
    ko.validation.registerExtenders();
    var email = ko.observable().extend({
        required: { message: 'You must enter a valid email id' },
        email: { message: 'Email address you entered is not valid' }
    });
    var password = ko.observable().extend({
        required: { message: 'Enter password, minimum of 6 characters' },
        minLength: 6
    });

    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        attached: attached,
        router: router,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        signIn: signIn,
        viewUrl : 'signin/index.html'
    };

    vm.errors = ko.validation.group(vm);
    return vm;

    function activate(id, querystring) {}

    function attached(view, parent) { }

    function signIn() {
        if (!vm.isValid()) {
            vm.errors.showAllMessages(true);
            return false;
        }
        //rest of logic         
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! it would be nice if you can highlight the important parts though, that way it would be easier to understand for others :)